# Google Cloud Platform [Errno 28] No space left on device with PyTorch

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I'm having a problem with pip installing my requirements.txt file on Google Cloud Platform. Here is the `df -h`. I'm SSHing into the instance but am confused about how to handle this problem. An suggestions about what commands to use?

```
Collecting torch
Killed
(bar-armor) andronikmk@instance-1:~/toxic-content-monitoring$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            1.8G     0  1.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           369M  876K  368M   1% /run
/dev/sda1       9.6G  6.1G  3.5G  64% /
tmpfs           1.8G     0  1.8G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           1.8G     0  1.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda15      105M  3.6M  101M   4% /boot/efi
/dev/loop0       94M   94M     0 100% /snap/core/9066
/dev/loop1       55M   55M     0 100% /snap/core18/1754
/dev/loop2       99M   99M     0 100% /snap/google-cloud-sdk/129
tmpfs           369M     0  369M   0% /run/user/1001
```

[image]

Comment: The `/dev/loop*` devices being 100% full is normal. You have plenty of free disk space elsewhere. Show your requirements.txt and a trace of activity. I recommended rebooting the system first. Note: You are using`tmpfs`. How much memory is allocated to your instance? What compute service are you using?

Comment: I'm SSHing into Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. I included a picture of my instance. I was thinking it has something to do with the allocated RAM. In addition, I'm installing and creating a conda env. After, I'm deploying using `gcloud app deploy app.yaml`